# How does the second "that" function in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, clauses

Here is the sentence:

> On December 5th Canada’s justice department
>   said that, on the same day **that**
>   the two presidents dined, it had arrested
>   Meng Wanzhou, the chief financial officer
>   of Huawei, a Chinese maker of telecoms
>   equipment, at America’s behest.

To make the sentence simpler, it should be

> On December 5th Canada’s justice department
>   said that it had arrested Meng Wanzhou at America’s behest on the same day **that** the two presidents dined.

My question is Does the second **that** introduce a time clause, relative clause, or other clauses? Can it be omitted?

Comment: "That" is a subordinator in both cases. The first introduces a declarative content clause, the second (which is optional) a relative clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be omitted.

The first "that" helps separate the day of the announcement from the day of the arrest. The second "that" does not seem to have a similar role to play.